# converting lines into one

Tags: linux, awk

could you please help to merge line in input file and produce output as below in descending order.

inputfile.txt

```
TerminalA/admin#
   51% used 
TerminalB/admin#
   62% used
TerminalC/admin#
   42% used
```

outputfile should contain as below in one line each terminal.

```
TerminalB/admin# 62% used
TerminalA/admin# 51% used
TerminalC/admin# 42% used
```

Below is code what I tried:

```
awk -f process1.awk | sort -t: -k1,2rn > output.txt
```

where awk script is:

```
$ cat process1.awk
/^$/  { print " " }
!/^$/ { printf("%s ",$0) }
```

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question as your efforts(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: Below i have tried but dont work..                                                                              awk -f process1.awk | sort -t: -k1,2rn > output.txt                                                       
cat process1.awk
/^$/ { print " " }
!/^$/ { printf("%s  ",$0) }

Comment: Kindly do add your code in your question. Also let us know why `TerminalB` line in input is coming at first line in output?

Comment: Hi, i need output in ascending order based on value in %

Comment: Just FYI please!! OP has posted efforts and question is clear now, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} FNR%2==0{print val OFS $0 | "sort -nrk2";next} {val=$0}' Input_file
```

***OR:*** In case you want to remove extra spaces before `%` line, which I think should be removed as per shown samples then try following:

```bash
awk '
{sub(/\r$/,"")}
FNR%2==0{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  print val OFS $0
  next
}
{
  val=$0
}
' Input_file | sort -nrk2
```

***Explanation:***

- Checking condition `FNR%2==0` to see if line number is even then do following.
- Printing variable val value followed by `OFS` followed by `$0`(current line).
- using  `| "sort -nrk2"` to further is basically sorting output in reverse/increasing order of 2nd column.
- `next` will skip all further statements from here.
- Statement `{val=$0}` will store current line's value into variable val. This statement will Only be executed when its an odd line number.

Comment: Nice and neat answer with clear explanation. I'd like to encourage the OP to accept the answer.

Comment: for me it dont work properly, what happening here is.. input file is actually output of shell script so when i run above script shared by Ravinder it actually remove name of terminal and show everuthing after it, like below                                                                             TerminalB/admin# <--- (this is removed) & 62% used <--- this show only ,                 But when i create file and manually copy same content as in input file and execute script then it work as expected, not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @anukalps, May be your file has control M characters in it. Can you run a command like: `cat -v Input_file` once on your file which you are passing to my `awk` code and see if you see Control M characters there?

Comment: Yes, it has ^M, how to correct this

Comment: @anukalps, ok Cool. Try my edited code now and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: It works, thanks V much.. i will run it on bulk files and update

Answer (score 6):

as a perl oneliner:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/\n\s+/ /g' /tmp/xx2 | sort -rk2
```

First we tell Perl to read the complete file (slurp) instead of reading it line by line. It might not work with files which do not fit into RAM.
Then we use regex to convert linebreaks and spaces into single space and reverse sorting by the second field with `sort -rk2`

Comment: This is not a pure perl line, because there is "|"

Answer (score 1):

Using simple awk with sort

```
$ awk ' { a=$0;getline; print a, $0 } ' input.txt | sort -k2 -nr 
TerminalB/admin#    62% used
TerminalA/admin#    51% used 
TerminalC/admin#    42% used
$
```

Or using standalone awk

```
$ awk ' BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc" } { a=$0;getline; b[$0]=a "" $0 } END { for(i in b) print b[i] } ' input.txt  
TerminalB/admin#   62% used
TerminalA/admin#   51% used 
TerminalC/admin#   42% used
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# <file paste -d" " - -|sort -k2 -r
TerminalB/admin#    62% used
TerminalA/admin#    51% used 
TerminalC/admin#    42% used
```